# Error when trying to convert dxf to shapefile?

Tags: qgis, dxf

I m using QGIS 2.18. I am getting the following error when I try to convert dxf to shapefile. The other software like online convertor and arcgis give no errors in converting the same shapefile. The program crashes.

Comment: When you [edit] your question there will be a picture button along the top that you can use to attach a screenshot. Be sure to always include errors as text in preference to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't care about any attributes attached to the features in the dxf, I simple load the dxf into QGis and use `save as` to "convert" it into shape format. Otherwise there's CAD2Shape, a proprietary converter.

Worth to mention: Be sure your dxf has no z-values, otherwise QGis might not be able to work with the file properly.